# jquery ui radio button validation works in Firefox, but errors in IE. .

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page that uses some jquery ui to style some radio buttons.  When a user selects one, jquery will identify which one was selected and then change the back ground color of a corresponding div that is down below (ultimately, they will actually call .load to fill the div with the contents of a dynamic page on the site, but for now, just coloring a div is fine).

It works peferctly in Firefox, but in Internet Explorer (or Internet Exploder as some call it), it complains that 'radio1' is undefined.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Button - Checkboxes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function() {
                    $( "#radio" ).button();
                    $( "#format" ).buttonset();
                });

            $('input:radio').change(function(){
                if($(radio1).is(':checked')){
                    $("#first").css("background-color","yellow");
                    $("#second").css("background-color","white");
                    $("#third").css("background-color","white");
                }else if($(radio2).is(':checked')){
                    $("#first").css("background-color","white");
                    $("#second").css("background-color","red");
                    $("#third").css("background-color","white");
                }else if($(radio3).is(':checked')){
                    $("#first").css("background-color","white");
                    $("#second").css("background-color","white");
                    $("#third").css("background-color","blue");
                } else {
                    $("#first").css("background-color","white");
                    $("#second").css("background-color","white");
                    $("#third").css("background-color","white");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style>
    #format { margin-top: 2em; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<form>
    <div id="format">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
    </div>
</form>

    <!-- The following divs will end up being populated via an ajax call based on checkbox selections -->
    <!-- Ultimately, checking a given checkbox should toggle the corresponding div -->
    <div id="first">
        First Div
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        Second Div
    </div>
    <div id="third">
        Third Div
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selectors should use id selectors to access the radio buttons.  I have no idea how this works in FF.

```
        $('input:radio').change(function(){
            if($("#radio1").is(':checked')){
                $("#first").css("background-color","yellow");
                $("#second").css("background-color","white");
                $("#third").css("background-color","white");
            }else if($("#radio2").is(':checked')){
                $("#first").css("background-color","white");
                $("#second").css("background-color","red");
                $("#third").css("background-color","white");
            }else if($("#radio3").is(':checked')){
                $("#first").css("background-color","white");
                $("#second").css("background-color","white");
                $("#third").css("background-color","blue");
            } else {
                $("#first").css("background-color","white");
                $("#second").css("background-color","white");
                $("#third").css("background-color","white");
            }
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working.  When I put the # sign in, Dreamweaver flags it as an error.  I made the changes anyway and tried it.  It loses the jQuery UI look on the radio buttons and then they don't work in Internet Explorer or Firefox.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why, but now it suddenly works.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kevin Maybe something was cached or jquery was not loaded in ie but cached in FF